# Why do two files viewed through the Dropbox API have the same id?

Tags: powershell, dropbox-api

I'm querying the Dropbox API using PowerShell successfully and getting all the files and folders using https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder. I'm putting the files and folders in separate arrays, but when trying to pull a single file by id out of them, there are a couple ids that reference two different files. Why is this?
Here's the snippet where it's happening:

```
try {
    $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $list_folder_url -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body)
} catch {
    $_.Exception.Response
}
$folders += $request.entries[0]

while ($request.has_more) {
    $cursor = $request.cursor
    $body = @{
        cursor="$cursor"
    }
    $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $folder_continue_url -Method Post -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body)
    $folders += $request.entries | ? { $_.'.tag' -eq "folder"}
    $files += $request.entries | ? { $_.'.tag' -eq "file"}
}

$file = $files | ? { $_.id -eq "id:**************" } ## Returns two very different files with the same id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox files IDs are case-sensitive, and some Dropbox file IDs may vary only by case.

In this code, you're using PowerShell's `-eq` operator, but according to [the PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#common-features):

> By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive.

So, you may be getting multiple entries where the file IDs are only different by case. Try using `-ceq` instead of `-eq`:

> To make a comparison operator case-sensitive, add a `c` after the `-`. For example, `-ceq` is the case-sensitive version of -eq.

Comment: That was it!! One stinking letter was a different case.
Thank you very much for the quick response.